# Static initialization of variables fails

Tags: c++, c++11, static, static-initialization

I stumbled across a problem from nowhere.

Suddenly my project that I am working on stopped working. I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 (LLVM 3.4, clang 5.1). The issue is that most static variables doesn't get initialized anymore at startup.

I didn't change anything which could lead to this problem but I'm curious to know what could have caused it and possibly how to solve it.

I'm talking about simple situations like:

```
// File.h 
class MyClass {
  static std::vector<MyObject*> data;
}

// File.cpp
std::vector<MyObject*> MyClass::data;
```

By running the program I get a length exception when trying to add elements to the vector, to realize that its size is just a garbage value. This happened to other static fields in other files with no apparent reason. The code itself is not used as a library but compiled as it is, and it worked flawlessly so far.

EDIT: building the release scheme doesn't show the problem, just to add more unpredictability.

EDIT: Things are even weirder than I expected. Another static variables which I manually initialized doesn't work too. The offending code is the following:

```
// .h
class MyClass {
  static MyClass* i;
public:
  static void init();
  static MyClass* getInstance();
}

// .cpp
MyClass* MyClass::i;

void MyClass::init() { i = new MyClass(); }
MyClass* getInstance() { return i; }
```

Now if I watch the values of `i` after the `init()` is called and when `getInstance()` is used for the first time I get two different addresses:

```
(lldb) p MyClass::i
(MyClass *) $0 = 0x09e36a50

(lldb) p MyClass::i
(MyClass *) $1 = 0x00620000
```

And I don't get how this is possible since (`init()`) is called just once (and before (getInstance()`)

Comment: Do they get used during construction of other static objects?

Comment: @hvd: No, actually the exception is raised when allocating a heap object once the program already started (which adds itself to the `std::vector`) but this is true for the other cases I found too.

Comment: Non-trival static variables like this caused me too many headaches so I stopped using them. A static local in a function returned is safer I find.

Comment: It's probably a dependency on the construction order of the static variables. It isn't always obvious that this is the case, but it usually is.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: the problem is that that static variable is not used by other static variables. It doesn't get initialized anymore at all. And all the `static` variables used so far in the code show the same behavior.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: indeed if you take a look at my second edit that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Perhaps bogus arguments to `memcpy` or similar, clobbering unrelated variables? Does your debugger support breaking on data changes? If so, you could set a regular breakpoint on `MyClass::init`, and after that finishes, break when `i` changes, and get a stack trace at that time.

Comment: Ask yourself in which order you expected these things to be constructed, and then ask yourself _why_.

Comment: OH and also you need to post a testcase please. Disappointing to see a 63k user not bothering to post a testcase.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare statically-scoped objects in different translation units, their relative order of construction is unspecified.

If, for example, you're trying to use MyClass::Data from code that runs as part of a constructor for some other statically-scoped object, in some other translation unit, it's not specified whether or not MyClass::Data is going to get constructed before or after the other statically-scoped object's constructor. If that code that accesses MyClass::Data gets invoked, and MyClass::Data is not constructed yet, that's obviously undefined behavior.

In most common C++ implementations, the order of construction depends upon what the linker does to piece together the final executable; and it is perfectly possible that various changes to your overall application now resulted in the linker stiching together the different object modules in a different order, and changing the relative construction order of statically-scoped objects.

Many implementations provide implementation-specific mechanisms to control the construction/initialization order of statically-scoped objects. gcc, for example, has an `init_priority` attribute that can be used to control this, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html